# Sweeping servo 90 degrees

Tags: servo

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
}

void loop() {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
}
```

I have found this code that makes servo go 180 and back, but when I switch 180 degrees with 90, which is what I need, my servo doesn't do that (I tried the code in Arduino simulator).

Do I have to change something elese in the code (like delay time) so it whould go 90 degrees up and then 90 down?

Here is the link of circuit:

https://circuits.io/circuits/3597808-servo-90-degrees

Comment: `when I swtich 180 degrees with 90 witch is what I need, my servo doesn't do that` - So what *does* it do? ... `(I tried the code in Arduino simulator)` - What happens with a *real* Arduino and a *real* servo? Simulators are merely an approximation. They can never be as good as the real thing.

Comment: @Majenko What he does is go 180 degrees up and starts sweeping between 180 and 90 degrees. It is really strage actually, beacuse I didnt inculde 180 degrees in code at all. You think Arduino simulator isn't accurate with servo's?

Comment: It sounds like the simulator is rubbish. Get a real servo for your Arduino. They are dirt cheap.

Comment: Either that or you are misinterpreting the servo output and what you think is 180° is actually 0°.

Comment: @Majenko I will try with real servo but the odd thing is that this first code that I posted is working just for 180 degrees and back, for every other number servo is turning in range between 90 and 180 degrees. BDW simulator is from Autodesk circuits.

Comment: Make video of the output and then post it.

Comment: @DatHa I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you **don't have to change any time delay** in order to get it rotating by 90 degrees, **delay would just change the speed** of rotation of the servo. The simulator you are using is at fault here as the sketch with **180 changed to 90** works flawlessly.

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
                // a maximum of eight servo objects can be created 

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position 

void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
} 


void loop() 
{ 
  for(pos = 0; pos < 90; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
  for(pos = 90; pos>=1; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
  {                                
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
}
```

MAKE SURE THAT YOU CHANGE **BOTH OF THE 180'S TO 90**.

Comment: That is what I did, and still nothing..

Answer (score 2):

I just created a simulation on Wokwi Arduino simulator based on your code and it works perfectly fine.
Here is the **permanent** [link](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/278918656574882312)
[image]

Comment: When you first click the "play button", the servo animation jumps around wildly. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will properly set up the PWM timers to output the correct signal to move the servo to the value set in 'pos'

```
myservo.write(pos);
```

It has nothing do with speed. The servo will try to reach 'pos' as fast as possible.

The delay(15) in your code is the delay time between each "myservo.write(pos);"

The for loop works like this:

```
myservo.write(0); // Go to 0 degrees
delay(15); // Wait 15ms
myservo.write(1); // Go to 1 degrees
delay(15); // Wait 15ms
myservo.write(2); // Go to 2 degrees
delay(15); // Wait 15ms
myservo.write(3); // Go to 3 degrees
delay(15); // Wait 15ms
```

etc...

The time in seconds it takes to make a rotation is (range_in_degrees x 15)/1000

e.g. 180deg x 15ms/1000 = 2.7 seconds
90deg x 15ms/1000 = 1.35 seconds

Increasing the 15ms delay will make the servo rotate slower.

Also, make sure that you change the 180 degrees to 90 in BOTH for loops. If you change the value in one, the servo will slowly sweep from 0 to 90, then jump to 180 and slowly swing back to 0 and repeat. (or vice versa, depending on which one you forgot to change)